# Can we find $n$ satisfying this equation for certain $p$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, number-theory

Let $r≥4$ be a positive integer. Let $n,p$ be two positive integers such that  $n≥p+2$ and $p_{m}$ be the $m^{th}$ prime.

Let us consider the equation:
$$\sum_{m=p+1}^{n-1} (2m-2p-p_{m}+p_{p})/r^{m²}=0$$

My **question** is: Can we find $n$ satisfying this equation for certain $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $p_p$ may be confusing, let me rename the integer $p$ as $k$.

From $p_{k+1}-p_k\ge2$ we get that $p_m-p_k\ge2(m-k)$. All the terms in the sum are non-positive. The only way in which it can be equal to $0$ is if all the terms are null. This happens in the following cases:

1. $k=2$, $n=4$
2. $k>2$, $n=k+2$ and $p_{k}$ is the smallest of a pair of twin primes.
3. $k=2$, $n=5$